# List attribute to Object attribute - ModelMapper

Tags: java, converters, modelmapper

I'm have some problems when I'm trying use the Model Mapper in Java 8.
I have a object "Person" and a object "Documents"
I have a situation similar to this:

```
public class Doc   {

  private Integer type;
  private List<Documento> documentos = null;
  private Boolean flag;
}

public class Document {

    private Long doc1;
    private Long doc2;
    private Long doc3;
}

public class Person {

    private Integer type;
    private Long doc1;
    private Long doc2;
    private Long doc3;
    private Boolean flag;
}

modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<Person, Doc>() { 
    @Override
    protected void configure() {                
        map().setType(source.getType());
        map().setDoc1(source.getDocument().get(0).getDoc1().longValue());
        map().setDoc2(source.getDocument().get(0).getDoc2().longValue());
        map().setDoc3(source.getDocument().get(0).getDoc3().longValue());
        map()setFlag(source.getFlag());
    }
});
```

But, this don't work.

Invalid source method java.util.List.get(). Ensure that method has zero parameters and does not return void.

I need to just the first object of document list.

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this solution from [Hugues M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6730571/hugues-m): [ModelMapper: Ensure that method has zero parameters and does not return void](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44775400/11148456) which answers a similar question involving the exception you are getting.